# lock article in joomla

Tags: joomla, passwords, yoothemes

Is any way to lock any article with any password. I look for this 2 days and nothing. I have idea, lock any urls with psw with .htaccess . . . .it is really?

I need from one page in joomla website use one psw. For second page in website second psw. I use j3. I need it for Phoca gallery and Yootheme ZOO.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Content Restriction](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction) category on the JED?

Answer (score 2):

Besides what lodder suggests, which would be my first choice, maybe it would be enough with assigning that content to specific usergroups and access levels, so that logging with specific name/pwd would be required to access that content. Depending on your exact needs, this could be enough, and would save you from adding extra extensions.